# Preserve a lock on shared resource in TC pipeline (between build configurations)

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I have a teamcity pipeline with multiple build configurations. Some of them need a database for testing. As of yet I have a pool of db schemas configured as a shared resource in TeamCity. Each build configuration lock a schema and then deploy DB into it as the first step. Now, I'd like to have a build configuration that would lock a resource, deploy db and then it should be used by other builds in the pipeline.

Something like:

```
deploy_db -> build_binaries -> unit tests
                            -> integration tests
                            -> ... other tests
```

I'd like to run test builds in parallel. For that I'd need to lock a schema in deploy_db and then pass a lock to other builds. Is it possible?

Perhaps I could lock any value from schema pool in deploy_db and then in other build configs use %dep.deploy_db.locked_schema% to lock a specific value.

However then it is probably possible that build for another branch can trigger deploy_db that could lock the same schema (using "lock any value") ? I mean it's probably possible if it's triggered after deploy_db finish and before next build executes lock? There would be a short period of time when lock is released after deploy_db and before it's acquired again. Technically another build could lock same value in this time. Is it possible to prevent this?

For example can I lock a value in the first build from a pipeline and release it in the last one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not yet supported. You can watch/vote for corresponding [request in the issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-36313)